# viewDidLoad is called differently in iOS8 vs iOS7?

Tags: ios, objective-c, ios8

I have a piece of code that runs fine on iOS7, but has issues in iOS8.

It is a popup, that is initialized from a nib and immediately after, it's show method is called.

The problem is, that the initFromNib in iOS8 returns immediately, before calling viewDidLoad.

Consequently all IBOutlets, that the code relies on in show are nil.

The same code is used at multiple occasions, it works with a datepicker embedded in the popup, but it seems that the tableview, that is embedded in the popup in this special case is not initializing immediately on initFromNib.

To repeat the question: Is this a new behavior in iOS8 and 
How should I handle this case in objC: 
Init a popup from nib and show it immediately after initialization has been finished.

Currently, I would implement my show method as a delegate that is called at the end of viewDidLoad, but this would integrate too much external workflow into the popup for my opinion. But then, I am not really experienced in iOS development ...

Thanks for helping out or pointing me to matching resources.

UPDATE: This is the code calling the view

```
- (void)onButtonTapped:(id)sender {
    if(shouldResignFirstResponder){
        [[[UIApplication sharedApplication] keyWindow] endEditing:YES];
    }
    isFirstResponder = YES;
    if (self.beginEditingBlock!=nil){
        self.beginEditingBlock([self fieldId]);
    }
    JXCheckListPopoverController *popover = [[JXCheckListPopoverController alloc]
          initWithNibName:@"JXCheckListPopoverController" bundle:nil];
    if([self getEditableFieldType] == EditableField_multipleStrings) {
        valuesBeforeEditing = [self.fieldValues copy];
        [popover setupPopoverWithParams:params delegate:self 
                 fieldValues:self.fieldValues readOnly:readOnly];
    } else {
        NSMutableDictionary *selectedValue = [[NSMutableDictionary alloc] 
                        initWithObjectsAndKeys:fieldValue, @"selectedValue", nil];
        self.fieldValueBeforeEditing = fieldValue ? fieldValue : @"";
        [popover setupPopoverWithParams:params 
                 delegate:self fieldValues:selectedValue readOnly:readOnly];
    }
    [popover show:self.bounds parent:self];
    [[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter] postNotificationName:@"fieldSelected" object:self];
    self.startDate = [NSDate date];
}
```

viewDidLoad is called after this method has finished. I understand, that this is somewhat uncool, but I inherited this code as a bad heritage and would like to understand how to rework the workflow. As there may be hundreds of popover views present during editing (present but not visible), I cannot create them all upfront - at least not as far as as I understand the code.

This is the show method:

```
- (void)show:(CGRect)rect parent:(UIView *)parent {
    if ([self.popoverController isPopoverVisible]){
         [self.popoverController dismissPopoverAnimated:YES];
    }

    UIPopoverController *popover = [[UIPopoverController alloc]initWithContentViewController:self];
    popover.delegate = self;

    const CGFloat height = contentTableView.rowHeight* possibleValues.count;

    CGRect screenRect = [[UIScreen mainScreen] bounds];
    CGFloat screenHeight = screenRect.size.height;

    //todo: replace hardcoded sizes here
    [popover setPopoverContentSize:CGSizeMake(350.0, MIN(height,screenHeight))];

    self.popoverController = popover;

    if (parent.window!=nil){
        [self.popoverController presentPopoverFromRect:rect inView:parent permittedArrowDirections:UIPopoverArrowDirectionAny animated:YES];
    }

    [[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter] postNotificationName:NOTIF_popupShow object:nil];
}
```

Comment: has viewDidLoad get called at all on iOS8?

Comment: Your issue is really unclear. Perhaps you should post your code from `initFromNib` and `viewDidLoad` and explain what issue you have with that code under iOS 8.

Comment: @sha no, I wrote the problem unclear. The viewDidLoad stops in the debugger after finishing the method above. Thus, initializing the popup has not finished when I call `show`. Inside show, the IBOutlets are nil. In ios7, the code runs fine.

Comment: Where is viewDidLoad code that doesn't get executed properly?

Comment: @sha that code is not the code in question. it is called, but at unexpected time. again, in ios7, when initfromnib returns, all iboutlets are done, viewdidload is finished, in ios8, vdl is called after the method is finished, and the iboutlets are nil when calling show.

Comment: The code you have in `viewDidLoad` can explain what you're trying to do there, and where is the correct place to execute such code (in case it should not be called in `viewDidLoad`)

Comment: Believe me: I do understand the view lifecycle, but it has changed for me in ios8. Do you know about this? My question is: when can I savely call the show method in ios8?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have found a solution to the problem.

I have changed the code to set the height of the tableview contained in the popup in the `viewWillAppear` method:

```
const CGFloat height = contentTableView.rowHeight* possibleValues.count;
CGFloat screenHeight = screenRect.size.height;
[popover setPopoverContentSize:CGSizeMake(350.0, MIN(height,screenHeight))];
```

This did not hurt the logic and it solved the problem.

The answer to the question is possibly that some change was there in nib loading, but I could not find a reference anywhere.

So I accept my answer as correct, as it solves my problem, but I feel kind of bad about it, because it does not explain the real issue. I have given the other persons answering a "+1" on their answers.

Answer (score 2):

The problem is that you were *always* doing this wrong. iOS 8 has merely exposed the problem. Keep in mind what `viewDidLoad` *means*. It means that this view has loaded and that any outlets are now connected. Nothing more. It exists, but that is all. In particular, it is *not* in the interface yet. So what you were doing in `viewDidLoad`, you were doing *too soon*. Use `viewDidAppear:` or `viewDidLayoutSubviews`, for example, to know when the view is actually in the interface and we are ready to do something else.

Comment: viewDidLoad is not the problem, the problem is, that viewDidLoad is called "too late" for the purpose of calling show. It is a symptom of my problem: Since viewDidLoad has not run until the `show` line, I now understand, why the show method finds all the IBOutlets as nil.

Comment: Right, I didn't read carefully enough. Modified my answer to mention the fact that outlets are not connected until `viewDidLoad`; that doesn't make my answer right for your particular issue, but it comes a little closer to focusing on the real issue. :) You should probably give your own answer solving the problem yourself (and after a couple of days you can accept your own answer); that is perfectly good Stack Overflow etiquette.

Answer (score 1):

Behavior for popovers has changed in iOS8. I'm not sure about regular view lifecycle thought. One would think that viewDidLoad will be called in a sync manner when you instantiate view from a XIB file, but judging by your comments it's not the case.

If I were on your place - I would try to create a sample small project where you can pin-point the problem and solution exactly. I know that re-factoring large body of code might not be an easy solution, but it might be necessary. In my projects I'm trying to wrap application logic for presenting alerts and popovers in a way so all differences between OS versions and devices are hidden from the application code and can adjusted easily.